# Timeout error from SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

i am executing a procedure using a for loop . The loop limit is some times 1000 or above . The code and procedure works good but some times i got an error as

**A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)**

This is My Data

```
public string updateselstatus(int sid, string[] trnasId, string[] resparr)
    {
        string ret = "";
        try
        {
            //con.Open();
            for (int j = 0; j < trnasId.Length; j++)
            {
                con.Open();
                string a = trnasId[j].Trim().ToString();
                string b = resparr[j].Trim().ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("OIB_updateselstatus", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsid", trnasId[j].Trim().ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", resparr[j].Trim().ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            ret = ex.Message.ToString();
            return ret;
        }
        //finally { con.Close(); }
    }
```

and my procedure is

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[OIB_updateselstatus]
  @status varchar(50),@smsid varchar(100),@sid int
  as
  begin
  update OIB_SmsHistory set IBH_Status=@status where IBH_Smsid=@smsid and IBH_M_idno=@sid
  end
```

is their any fault in my code or query . How can i over come this time out error. Is it depends my internet speed

Comment: Why open and close the db each loop?

Comment: @BugFinder the loop runs upto 5-10 mins .. So i think the connection losses because of it . May be a bad decision ..

Comment: the connection would only terminate due to lack of life, this is telling you the query took too long

Comment: you need to work out why your query is so slow! as at first glance it looks like its going to update 1 line - however that cant be the case..  We cant tell without your data, your servers etc.. you need to work it out with the dba if you have one

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you for your help . i will check it . Can i accept it if it only update  one or two row at a time . the table consist more than 60,000+ data

Comment: You could do a transaction and batch them

Comment: @BugFinder It only update a row at a time ..

Comment: It maybe you're finding the network is blocking you due to 60k connections in very little time and it thinks you're a hacker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to your proc, it's not SQL Server error.

This error is reported by Network library, check here for the details:
[The semaphore timeout period has expired](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d99b4d8e-feeb-43cb-80af-3d4826340a2c/the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired?forum=sqldataaccess)

Comment: can you please go through the  answer that i post below

Comment: @Jks, I have no idea about cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()/adp.Fill(dt), I know well SQL Server side, not C#, sorry.Does it change network protocol to use or the connection is the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know its correct or not. When i change my code as this i can escape from the time out error

**Old Code**

```
public string updateselstatus(int sid, string[] trnasId, string[] resparr)
    {
        string ret = "";
        try
        {
            //con.Open();
            for (int j = 0; j < trnasId.Length; j++)
            {
                con.Open();
                string a = trnasId[j].Trim().ToString();
                string b = resparr[j].Trim().ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("OIB_updateselstatus", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsid", trnasId[j].Trim().ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", resparr[j].Trim().ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            ret = ex.Message.ToString();
            return ret;
        }
        //finally { con.Close(); }
    }
```

**New Code**

```
   public string updateselstatus(int sid, string[] trnasId, string[] resparr)
    {
        string ret = "";
        try
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < trnasId.Length; j++)
            {
                //string a = trnasId[j].Trim().ToString();
                //string b = resparr[j].Trim().ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("OIB_updateselstatus", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsid", trnasId[j].Trim().ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", resparr[j].Trim().ToString());
                // New Code 
                adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    adp.Fill(dt);

                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    ret = exp.Message.ToString();
                    return ret;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ret = ex.Message.ToString();
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

I change cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() to adp.Fill(dt) and also the changes that related to this . I dont know  whether its right or wrong . but works fine for me